# How to predict the outcome variables using a saved pipeline when the data set does not contain the actual outcome?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, pipeline

I have a data set that contains the following columns: outcome (this is the outcome that we want to predict), and raw (a column that consists of text). I want to develop an ML model that will predict the outcome from the raw column. I have trained an ML model in Databricks using the following pipeline:

```
regexTokenizer = RegexTokenizer(inputCol="raw", outputCol="words", pattern="\\W")
countVec = CountVectorizer(inputCol="words", outputCol="features")
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="outcome", outputCol="label").setHandleInvalid("skip").fit(trainDF)
inverter = IndexToString(inputCol="prediction", outputCol="prediction_label", labels=indexer.labels)
nb = NaiveBayes(labelCol="label", featuresCol="features", smoothing=1.0, modelType="multinomial")
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[regexTokenizer, indexer, countVec, nb, inverter])
model = pipeline.fit(trainDF)
model.write().overwrite().save("/FileStore/project")
```

In another notebook, I load the model and try to predict the values for a new data set. This data set does not contain the outcome variable ("outcome" in this case):

```
model = PipelineModel.load("/FileStore/project")
score_output_df = model.transform(score_this)
```

When I try to predict the values for the new data set, I get an error message that the column "outcome" cannot be found. I suspect that this is due to the fact that some stages in the pipeline transform this column (the indexer and inverter stages are used to convert the outcome column to numbers and then back to string labels.).

My question is this, how can I load a saved model and use it to predict values when the original pipeline contains stages that have this column as an input.

Comment: Could you please add dummy data to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the problem and will post it here so that if someone faces the same problem they can benefit from it. The solution was simply to extract the stages that I want to use in the prediction and save them to the model as such:

```
model = PipelineModel.load("/FileStore/project")
stages1 = []
stages1 += [model.stages[0]]
stages1 += [model.stages[2]]
stages1 += [model.stages[3]]
stages1 += [model.stages[4]]
model.stages = stages1
score_output_df = model.transform(score_this)
```

In this code, I exclude the second step ([1]) because it contains the indexer. Once I do this, I can predict values when the "outcome" column is not available.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

`model.write().overwrite().save("/FileStore/project")`

you have to write it like this

`model.write().overwrite().save("/FileStore/project/model.sav")`

and then for loading you will use this

`model = PipelineModel.load("/FileStore/project/model.sav")`

`score_output_df = model.transform(score_this)`

Comment: This does not work. I still get the same error message.

Comment: ```model = PipelineModel.load("/FileStore/project")``` 

```score_output_df = model.transform(score_this)```

In this the data *score_this*. Is it having any column named outcome ?